# Join de 2 tablas por coincidencia aproximada (uniendo por el máximo valor que sea menor o igual)

Tags: excel, powerquery

Lo que quiero lograr es lo mismo que un `=BUSCARV(val;matriz;col;VERDADERO)` con coincidencias aproximadas (`VERDADERO` en el último parámetro), pero en PowerQuery (M).

**Explico** de nuevo y en detalle:
Tengo 2 tablas, `Tabla1` que es la principal y a la que quiero agregarle una categoría traída de la `Tabla2` (join).

> [image: Tabla1 y Tabla2]

Quiero generar una nueva tabla, la cual debería mantener los mismos valores de `Tabla1`, con una columna extra, la `Categoría` de `Tabla2`.

**Resultado esperado**:

> [image: Tabla Resultado]

En este ejemplo, el join para las 2 primeras filas coinciden perfecto, pero las últimas 2 toman el caso máximo donde
`Tabla1[Valor] >= Tabla2[ValorDesde]`

**Condiciones**: quiero hacer esto con PowerQuery (exclusivamente), ambas tablas pueden cambiar y al ejecutar el query quiero regenerar la tabla de resultados. Las categorías son un parámetro que yo no defino, por lo cual no me sirve hacer una columna personalizada con un `if` para cada condición ni nada similar. Las categorías son únicas, no hay valores duplicados y ya vienen ordenados de menor a mayor.

**Lo que intenté** hasta ahora (código abajo) fue generar una columna personalizada con el primer valor de `Tabla2[ValorDesde]` que cumple la condición, para luego hacer el join. Sin embargo, estoy uniendo los valores de la `Tabla2` por duplicado, y esto es claramente innecesario. Sé que cuando tenga muchos datos lo va a convertir en un cuello de botella.

**Ejemplo mínimo** (estoy generando las tablas manualmente para que puedan copiar y pegar en PowerQuery y reutilizar este mismo código):

```
let //Orígenes de datos
    Tabla1 = Table.FromRows({{"Uno", 1}, {"Dos",2}, {"Tres", 3.33}, {"Cuatro", 4.12345678}}, type table[Nombre=text, Valor=number]),
    Tabla2 = Table.FromRows({{0, "Inicial"}, {1, "Nuevo"}, {2, "Intermedio"}, {4, "Avanzado"}}, type table[ValorDesde=number, Categoría=text]),
    
    //Obtengo el valor que tiene que usar en el join (columna accesoria)
    ColParaJoin = Table.AddColumn(Tabla1, "ValorDesde",
        (fila) =>
            List.Max(
                List.Select(Tabla2[ValorDesde], (valorDesde) => valorDesde <= fila[Valor])
            )
        , type number
    ),

    //JOIN
    LeftOuterJoin = Table.NestedJoin( ColParaJoin, {"ValorDesde"}, Tabla2, {"ValorDesde"}, "ColParaJoin", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandCateg = Table.ExpandTableColumn(LeftOuterJoin, "ColParaJoin", {"Categoría"}, {"Categoría"}),

    //Elimino la columna accesoria
    ElimValorDesde = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandCateg,{"ValorDesde"})
in
    ElimValorDesde
```

Logro el resultado esperado, pero...

**Pregunta**: ¿hay alguna forma más eficiente de hacer el join con el máximo valor que sea menor o igual y obtener la última columna? ¿Se puede hacer sin estar uniendo 2 veces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui es como hacer todo en Powerquery.

[https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/power-query-approximate-match-vlookup#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Load%20both%20the,tab%20%3E%20From%20Table%2FRange.&text=Step%204%3A%20Add%20a%20Conditional,from%20the%20Bonus%20Rate%20table](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/power-query-approximate-match-vlookup#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Load%20both%20the,tab%20%3E%20From%20Table%2FRange.&text=Step%204%3A%20Add%20a%20Conditional,from%20the%20Bonus%20Rate%20table).

Hacer un join
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Expandir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Insertar Columna
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ordenar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Copiar Categoria Abajo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eliminar Null
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Nombre", type 
text}, {"Valor", type number}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Valor"}, Table2, 
{"ValorDesde"}, "Table2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", 
{"ValorDesde", "Categoria"}, {"ValorDesde", "Categoria"}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", 
"Custom", each if [Valor] = null then [ValorDesde] else [Valor]),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"Custom", 
Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"Categoria"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each [Nombre] <> null 
and [Nombre] <> "")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudó. Añadí el código